# ContextSwitchDeadlock error on exception, retry

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I am currently trying to trap errors within my VB.net code when dealing with FTP Transfer using EDT.net.ftp. I have listed the complete subroutine for the write operation below. I have disconnected the network cable to my instrument to simulate error 57. this works correctly, but when I reconnect and retry the program gets stuck and finally gives me a ContextSwitchDeadlock error. I think I need to close the FTP connection before retrying it, but haven't got the command to do this. 
If I try to place FTPprocess.Quit() within the exceptions I get an error stating the FTPprocess is not declared.

Any help here would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub WriteFTPFile() 
    ' APS 15 Aug 2014 Create the script, and run it. This is in 2 stages. 1, create the script, 2 run the ftp script to retrieve the files.

    ' temp load the parsed data.
    Dim ArrayCount As Integer
    Dim LocalFile(3) As String
    Dim RemoteFile(3) As String
    Dim LocalFilePath As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim user As String = "username"
    Dim password As String = "password"
    'Dim LanguageFileName As String
    RemoteFile(1) = "IN_Tool.csv"
    RemoteFile(2) = "IN_Joint.csv"
    'LocalFilePath = "D:\Technologies\Henrob\IP Addresses\192.168.50.200"
    LocalFile(1) = "D:\Technologies\Henrob\IP Addresses\192.168.50.200\IN_Tool.csv"
    LocalFile(2) = "D:\Technologies\Henrob\IP Addresses\192.168.50.200\IN_Joint.csv"
    Path = "192.168.50.200"

    ' break out the LocalFilePath
    LocalFilePath = ""
    Dim LocalPath As String() = LocalFile(1).Split(CChar("\"))
    ReDim Preserve LocalPath(UBound(LocalPath) - 1)
    LocalFilePath = Join(LocalPath, CChar("\"))

    ' store the current directory
    Dim CurrentDir As String = CurDir()
    System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(LocalFilePath)

      ' and create the StopRead.txt
    Using StopRead As StreamWriter = File.CreateText("StopRead.txt")
        StopRead.WriteLine("no text")
        StopRead.Flush()
    End Using
    ' Step 2 transfer the files.
    Dim Retry As Boolean = True
    While Retry
        Try
            ' send the files
            Dim FTPprocess As FTPClient = Nothing
            FTPprocess = New FTPClient(Path)
            'FTPprocess.RemoteHost = Path
            FTPprocess.Login(user, password)
            FTPprocess.ConnectMode = FTPConnectMode.PASV
            FTPprocess.TransferType = FTPTransferType.BINARY
            ' stop the PLC Polling
            FTPprocess.Put("StopRead.txt", "StopRead.txt")
            For ArrayCount = 1 To UBound(RemoteFile)
                If Len(RemoteFile(ArrayCount)) > 0 Then
                    'If FTPprocess.Exists(RemoteFile(ArrayCount)) = False Then
                    FTPprocess.Put(RemoteFile(ArrayCount), RemoteFile(ArrayCount))
                    'End If
                End If
            Next
            ' Restart the PLS Polling
            FTPprocess.Delete("StopRead.txt")
            FTPprocess.Quit()

            ' delete the Stop Read file
            File.Delete("StopRead.txt")
            ' everything ok then we can continue
            Retry = False
            ' catch any exceptions, this can be built on as errors are seen
        Catch ex As Exception
            Select Case Err.Number
                Case 5 ' Cannot find file
                    If MessageBox.Show("Cannot locate file. Ensure File exists, then retry", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel) = DialogResult.Retry Then
                        Retry = True
                    Else
                        Retry = False
                    End If
                Case 57 ' Cannot find Drive Connection
                    If MessageBox.Show("Cannot locate Drive on " & Path & "." & vbNewLine & "Ensure Drive with this IP Address is attached, then retry", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel) = DialogResult.Retry Then
                        Retry = True
                    Else
                        Retry = False
                    End If
                Case Else
                    If MessageBox.Show(CStr(Err.Number) & " " & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel) = DialogResult.Retry Then
                        Retry = True
                    Else
                        Retry = False
                    End If
            End Select

        End Try
    End While

            ' reset the current directory
            System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(CurrentDir)
            WriteResults = "Completed Write " & Now & vbNewLine 'SR.ReadToEnd 'returns results of the command window
            WriteUpdateText()

            Dim debugtext As String = "Write " & CStr(Now)
            Debug.Print(debugtext)
            Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Comment: ContextSwitchDeadlock is not an error, it is just a debugger diagnostic.  It tells you that your UI thread has been dead to the world for a minute.  Something you surely already know, ought to be pretty visible with a frozen window that's not responsive.  Network timeouts are pretty long, you make it worse by re-trying.  High odds that you just need to wait longer than a minute.  Run this kind of code on a worker thread to avoid the frozen UI issue.

Comment: Hi Hans, Thanks for the quick answer. in this case the retry shouldn't wait at all. The network is re-attached, and 'ping'able. It appears to stop in a loop trying to run the line FTPprocess = New FTPClient(Path), as if it is trying to re-open a still open channel. Thanks again